# include the custom field in Woocommerce in my IPN

Tags: wordpress, paypal-ipn, woocommerce

Hi I use Woocommerce plugin. All works great, I have added a custom field or attribute to a product which is fine and it shows on the products detail page but my problem is getting this data to come through in the PayPal IPN.

I am trying to edit this code as I believe the custom field data is held in meta but cannot find the id of my custom field or where to add it:

```
// Cart Contents
                    $item_loop = 0;
                    if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
                            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                                    if ( $item['qty'] ) {

                                            $item_loop++;

                                            $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

                                            $item_name         = $item['name'];

                                            $item_meta = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item['item_meta'] );
                                            if ( $meta = $item_meta->display( true, true ) )
                                                    $item_name .= ' ( ' . $meta . ' )';

                                            $paypal_args[ 'item_name_' . $item_loop ]         = html_entity_decode( $item_name, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
                                            $paypal_args[ 'quantity_' . $item_loop ]         = $item['qty'];
                                            $paypal_args[ 'amount_' . $item_loop ]                 = $order->get_item_subtotal( $item, false );

                                            if ( $product->get_sku() )
                                                    $paypal_args[ 'item_number_' . $item_loop ] = $product->get_sku();
                                    }
                            }
                    }
```

Need to change script that send "order_id" to PayPal on script to send my custom field to PayPal. That's all.

Appreciate any answers. Thanks.!

Comment: You should post the code into your question.

Comment: I Think this is the code that needs to be updated as this is where the META is and I belive custom fields are in WP Post Meta.